# ASP.NET Linq where filters checking dates not working

Tags: asp.net, linq

So on my page I have two date boxes where users can choose a from and to date. The problem is when I enter for example the below. I get items which actually have a date greater than 05/04/2012, which according to the below should not happen.

Basically what I am trying to achieve is

- If from date is entered then date >= from date
- if to date is entered then date <= to date
- if both are entered then date >= from date and date <= to date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your `cl.claimStatus.Any` will return `true` if any of the items in the `claimStatus` list are less than 05/04/2012.  Thus, your statement would look like the following:

```
filteredClaims = filteredClaims.Where(c1=>true);
```

...thus returning everything.

Comment: But I am getting items which are after 05/04/2012 i.e 05/07/2012. Sorry I am not following what you are saying